# Insert OLE/ActiveX objects (Excel) into ArcMap Layout using ArcObjects c#

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#, add-in

I am trying to create an ArcMap Add-In in which I need to insert a sheet of an Excel file into the Layout using SDK.net ArcObjects. I can't find the slightest example of how to implement this. The insertion should be as via the ArcMap interface:
"Navigate to Insert > Object. In the Insert Object dialog box, select Create from file. Click Browse to go to the location of the Excel file and select it."

Comment: Have you reviewed [this discussion](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcobjects-sdk-questions/arcdesktop-10-5-adding-excel-object-to-mxd-with-arcobjects/m-p/421637) over on geonet? Geonet should be your go to place for technical advice on ArcObjects.

Comment: Thank you, I will understand